# Why is mySQL in PHP returning null results?

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I am trying to migrate ~55K records from a mySQL server over to MongoDB. I can't do this via any of the easily accessible methods like JSON/CSV importing because the data storage method (the way it is structured) will be very different. Because of this, I have created a script in php that is designed to do this.

The issue I have been running into with this is that over large sets of data (not reproducible using smaller data sets even when the smaller set includes problem entries) the queries will occasionally report no data despite the entry existing. It absolutely exists because when php accesses that specific entry directly or it is included in a smaller data set, it works just fine. For instance, in the import to a text file, i only received ~42k/54k records.

In the echo I am receiving through the url the php file is called through, I am showing that the query is called the correct number of times, but there are many records that are showing as not existing, thus the answering echo is blank. The code is included below:

```
//Makes a connection to the database
$conn = makeConnection();

$filename = '/home/dbserverdownload.txt';
$file = fopen($filename, 'a');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM maintable ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1";
$resultID = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$ID = mysqli_fetch_object($resultID);
echo $ID->ID;
//loops through the database and appends the data to the file as it goes
for($var=2; $var <= $ID->ID; $var++){
    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM servertable WHERE ID = '$var'";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
    $values = mysqli_fetch_object($result1);

    $id =  $values->ID;
    $ip = $values->IP;
    $port = $values->port;
    $running = $values->running;
    $afk = $values->afk;
    $gamemode = $values->gamemode;
    $maxplayers = $values->maxplayers;
    $spawnprotection = $values->spawnprotection;
    $whitelist = $values->whitelist;
    $enablequery = $values->enablequery;
    $enablercon = $values->enablercon;
    $rconpassword = $values->rconpassword;
    $motd = $values->motd;
    $achievements = $values->announceplayerachievements;
    $allowflight = $values->allowflight;
    $spawnanimals = $values->spawnanimals;
    $spawnmobs = $values->spawnmobs;
    $forcegamemode = $values->forcegamemode;
    $hardcore = $values->hardcore;
    $pvp = $values->pvp;
    $difficulty = $values->difficulty;
    $generatorsettings = $values->generatorsettings;
    $levelname = $values->levelname;
    $levelseed = $values->levelseed;
    $leveltype = $values->leveltype;
    $autosave = $values->autosave;

if($ip == "148.57.44.10"){
  //if the server is server1
  $servername = "server1".$port;
} else if ($ip == "165.108.22.199"){
  //if the server is server2
  $servername = "server2".$port;
} else{
  $servername = "";
}



//Adds all content that was already gained to the JSON string
$startingContent = "{\"_id\":\"$servername\",
                    \"ip\":\"$ip\",
                    \"port\":\"$port\",
                    \"running\":\"$running\",
                    \"afk\":\"$afk\",
                    \"gamemode\":\"$gamemode\",
                    \"maxplayers\":\"$maxplayers\",
                    \"spawnprotection\":\"$spawnprotection\",
                    \"whitelist\":\"$whitelist\",
                    \"enablequery\":\"$enablequery\",
                    \"enablercon\":\"$enablercon\",
                    \"rconpassword\":\"$rconpassword\",
                    \"motd\":\"$motd\",
                    \"announceplayerachievements\":\"$achievements\",
                    \"allowflight\":\"$allowflight\",
                    \"spawnanimals\":\"$spawnanimals\",
                    \"spawnmobs\":\"$spawnmobs\",
                    \"forcegamemode\":\"$forcegamemode\",
                    \"hardcore\":\"$hardcore\",
                    \"pvp\":\"$pvp\",
                    \"difficulty\":\"$difficulty\",
                    \"generatorsettings\":\"$generatorsettings\",
                    \"levelname\":\"$levelname\",
                    \"levelseed\":\"$levelseed\",
                    \"leveltype\":\"$leveltype\",
                    \"autosave\":\"$autosave\"
                  }";



echo $startingContent."<br/>";


//This is the JSON data that will be passed to mongo

if(strlen($ip)>6){
    if (fwrite($file, $startingContent) === FALSE) {
        echo "Cannot write to file ($filename) with $startingContent";
        exit;
    }
}
}
```

I have also tried this with a query that pulls a significant number(all, half, a quarter, etc) of the results in one chunk instead of tons of individual queries. The end result of that experiment was that a variable number of records were updated (usually a seemingly random number between 400 and 4000) each time it was run. Does anyone have any idea why this might be occurring? If not, should I just make my own program to iterate over the CSVs that I can export from mySQL?

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to perform the `SELECT` statements individually in an incrementing `for` loop rather than just query them all at once and act on them while fetching in a loop? Do you have `display_errors` enabled? At the top of your script `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in case you are experiencing timeouts.  Finally, it would be advisable to use `json_encode()` on an associative array instead of manually building the JSON string. Those look like minecraft params and I assume are simple strings, but things like unescaped quotes in them can cause issues.

Comment: Your code seems to assume that there will be no gaps in the ID sequence in `servertable`. If you've ever deleted a row from the table that will leave gaps.

Comment: Are the IDs in `maintable` really correlated to the IDs in `servertable`?

Comment: This is a fairly new table and as such there have been no deletions yet so there are no gaps. And yes, though maintable is a rename of a different table

Answer (score 0):

First of all, replace your query `$sql = "SELECT * FROM maintable ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1";`
 with this `$sql = "SELECT MAX(ID) as ID FROM maintable";` for better performance.

Your problem here is that you probably has a query that return false, then your application dies. Let's say, for example, your loop tries to query `ID=3`, but there is no row in your database with this ID. Then the next lines throws a exception, that you are not seeing. You could use set `display_errors=On` in you dev machine `php.ini`.

Use this to check if your have results to fetch:

```
....
for($var=2; $var <= $ID->ID; $var++){
    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM servertable WHERE ID = '$var'";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);

    if($result) {
        $values = mysqli_fetch_object($result1);

        $id =  $values->ID;
        $ip = $values->IP;
        ....
```

Comment: Wouldn't this allow for a loss of records? There is (guaranteed) a record for every number between 2 and 52,000+. If it returns a false on any one of those, there is a problem and I would prefer if it stopped altogether and allowed me to figure out why. Instead it is just pushing ahead despite skipping over nearly 10k records.

Comment: If you need to stop, add a `else` in the end and do what you think it's better to do, maybe send a notification, put a `die('gap here');` or something. At least, try my solution and check if this is your issue here.